# Geochart google . Click Country and show the provinces

Tags: javascript

any idea for show the regions of a country when I click in a country?

document.jsonGeoChart   = [{"Argentina":{"count":"5","regions":{"Cordoba Province":"2","La Pampa Province":"2","Santa Fe Province":"1"}}},{"Uruguay":{"count":"1","regions":{"Montevideo":"1"}}}];

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

```
  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = new  google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cantidad');

  $.each(document.jsonGeoChart,function(item){
      $.each(document.jsonGeoChart[item],function(item_){
         data.addRow([item_,parseInt(document.jsonGeoChart[item][item_].count)]);

             var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data2.addColumn('string', 'Province');
            data2.addColumn('number', 'Device Count');

            $.each(document.jsonGeoChart[item][item_].regions,function(item__){
                console.log(item__ + ' '  +document.jsonGeoChart[item][item_].regions[item__]);
            })

      });

  });





    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_2_map'));
    chart.draw(data, options);


};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google GeoChart has sub-region data for Argentina and Uruguay, for it to zoom-in and highlight.

What you need is something like a **VectorWorkz GeoChart** that can provide you sub-region info for the countries you are interested in and into which you can drill down into. Take a look at the answer to this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561064/google-geochart-buttons/24576936#24576936